# array_splice() : Insert array into 2-dimensional array at index [PHP]

Tags: php, arrays, array-splice

I am trying to insert an array into a 2-dimensional array at a specific position.
According the manual, i should be able to do this with array_splice(), but it only deletes the contents of my receiving array without insertion.

I want to get an array with all the values (arrays) of $receivingArray plus the new value (array).

What am I doing wrong??

manual info:

> array array_splice ( array &$input , int $offset [, int $length [, mixed  $replacement = array() ]] )
>
> If length is specified and is zero, no elements will be removed.
> If replacement is just one element it is not necessary to put array() around > it, unless the element is an array itself, an object or NULL.

input:

```
$newArray = array_splice($receivingArray, 0, 0, array($value));
```

result: $newArray is an empty array

input :

```
$newArray = array_splice($receivingArray, 1, 0, array($value));
```

result: $newArray is an empty array

this input:

```
print_r($receivingArray);
print_r(array($value));
$newArray = array_splice($receivingArray, 1, 1, array($value));
print_r($newArray);
```

gives: (interestingly)

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [primaryID] => 0
            [category_id] => 1
            [title] => sports
            [description] => 
            [selected] => 
            [level] => 0
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 4
            [primaryID] => 0
            [category_id] => 0
            [title] => programming
            [description] => 
            [selected] => 
            [level] => 0
        )

)
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [primaryID] => 1
            [category_id] => 1
            [title] => soccer
            [description] => 
            [selected] => 
            [level] => 1
        )

)
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 4
            [primaryID] => 0
            [category_id] => 0
            [title] => programming
            [description] => 
            [selected] => 
            [level] => 0
        )

)
```

Comment: First of all don't give this much array output . confusing. Just show initial `$receivingArray`. what you tried(code) and what your expected output. not whole array just a part of it which make sense to all of us.

Comment: ok, ill edit, thanks

Comment: you got the solution. no need to do now. thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the docs for [`array_splice()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-splice.php)

> **Return Values**
>
> Returns the array consisting of the extracted elements.

```
$newArray = array_splice($receivingArray, 0, 0, array($value));
```

array_splice modifies its input, so the results you're looking for are in `$receivingArray` and not `$newArray`

Answer (score 0):

I missed the fact that array_slice() doesn't actually return its output, but rather acts upon the receiving array itself, which is passed by reference. I didn't notice that there is an ammpersand in front of the first parameter in the manual specification.

this input:

```
print_r($receivingArray);
print_r(array($value));
array_splice($receivingArray, 0, 0, array($value));
print_r($receivingArray);
```

gives the correct result:

```
Array 
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [primaryID] => 0
            [category_id] => 1
            [title] => sports
            [description] => 
            [selected] => 
            [level] => 0
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 4
            [primaryID] => 0
            [category_id] => 0
            [title] => programming
            [description] => 
            [selected] => 
            [level] => 0
        )

)
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [primaryID] => 1 
            [category_id] => 1
            [title] => soccer
            [description] => 
            [selected] => 
            [level] => 1
        )

)
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [primaryID] => 0
            [category_id] => 1
            [title] => sports
            [description] => 
            [selected] => 
            [level] => 0
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [primaryID] => 1
            [category_id] => 1
            [title] => soccer
            [description] => 
            [selected] => 
            [level] => 1
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 4
            [primaryID] => 0
            [category_id] => 0
            [title] => programming
            [description] => 
            [selected] => 
            [level] => 0
        )

)
```